# Derive the entity using split for non mathcing string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Need to derive the entity using split for non mathching as well in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Alias': ['AAA', 'AAA','TTTTTT', 'GGG'],
                         'att': ['LG.ident', 'Date','TTTTTT.DDD', 'attribute_test'],                                      
                        'ent': ['AAA', 'AAA','TTTTTT', 'GGG'],
                        'id': ['1', '2','3', '4']})
Code:
df['ent'] = np.where((df.Alias == 'AAA'),df['att'].str.split('.').str[0].fillna(df['Alias']),df.ent)

the ent value for second record supposed to get 'AAA' as below but the Date value is being captured wrong with above code

Expected output:
    Alias            att             ent        id
0   AAA              LG.ident        LG          1
1   AAA              Date            AAA         2
2   TTTTTT           TTTTTT.DDD     TTTTTT       3
3   GGG              attribute_test GGG          4
```

Answer (score 0):

Add subfilter on `att` column:

```
df['ent'] = np.where(df.Alias.eq('AAA') & df['att'].str.contains('\.'),
                     df['att'].str.split('.').str[0], df.ent)
```

---

```
    Alias             att     ent id
0     AAA        LG.ident      LG  1
1     AAA            Date     AAA  2
2  TTTTTT      TTTTTT.DDD  TTTTTT  3
3     GGG  attribute_test     GGG  4
```